# Ntfs "No permissions have been assigned for this object"

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-permissions, acl

We occasionally observe damaged permissions on folders with the error: `No permissions have been assigned for this object`

The affected systems are mostly Windows 7 but also Terminal Server 2008 and later, not affected is Server 2003 Terminal Server.

[image: No permissions have been assigned for this object]

**Problems**
Problems come up when a sub folder is created. Because the sub folder does not inherit any permissions, it gets only the default permissions (owner etc.)

**Already done**
We compard the affected systems but they have no significant matches in installed software or drivers.

Currently we look for a method how to detect those faults before our software runs on an error. Tools like AccessEnum doesn't reveal it. Chksk doesn't find any errors.

But our most important is the question what is the cause of this?

Does anybody have experience with that?

**Edit:**
Mostly the local temp folder (C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp) **itself** is affected by the error. At least our sofware gets the errors there. But I know, that other folders can also be affected.

We saw the error on about 40 customer systems and, once fixed, it seems not to come back again.

The fix is quite easy. Add system - full control (or something else) to the permissions and the old permissions reappear again.

**Edit2**

**How dows the problem look like exactly:**

- The permissions on the temp folder are corrupted (as shown in screenshot)
- In this state everybody can do anything in the folder (delete, create etc.)
- Our installer runs elevated and creates a subfolder `.\temp\ProgramInfos`. That works (see above).
- Because the temp folder hase no active permissions, the `ProgramInfos` folder does'nt inherit anything. So `ProgramInfos` gets only the rights for `Administrators, System`
- The installed application later is running not elevated
- The not elevated user can't access the folder - in not elevated state he isn't administrator.

It's not a general error. We are installed on ten thousands of computers and till today only about 40 had that error.

(In lack of an english system with that error the screnshot does not show an authentic message but in german it's the same)

Comment: When you look at the security tab of the parent folder and go to advanced, what do you see in the Apply To section is it set to Apply To this folder, subfolders and files?

Comment: @CharlesH no everything is blank. Before the permissions got damaged they were set. After making any change to the permissions of such a folder (like add system - full control) the previous permissions reappear again and everything is fine)

Comment: Where are these files stored? Are they stored in one place and accessed throughout multple places through the network? If so, it might be that a harddisk is dying.

Comment: Hmm anything in the system event logs when this happens (anything relating to filesystem corruption) might be worth running a CHKDSK to see if there are any bad clusters. I've not heard of anything like this being OS related normally hardware. However might be worth running a SFC /SCANNOW to fix any OS system file issues.

Comment: @LPChip good idea. Forgot it, look at the edit.

Comment: @CharlesH It seems not to bee an error of orphan records or an index error. We tried on some systems chkdsk, but with no result. We don't know when the error happened but we compared the eventlogs of some affected systems and didn't found any matches.

Comment: @boboes Really odd one.. The only suggestion I can make going forward is to investigate turning on Folder Audit for any new/unaffected customers and see if you can capture the event in the audit log to try and see what the cause was...

Comment: How are these folders being created in the first place?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 by the operating system `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp`

Comment: Ahh, so it's not folders within that Temp folder, it's the temp folder itself?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Yes, the temp folder itself (i will update the question). Our elevated installation creates a subfolder under temp (that works). The software later isn't elevated and can't access the sub folder. Due to missing permissions to inherit the subolder got only administrators and system rights.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself, or I'm just not following. :) So the problem is permissions missing/not inheriting  (from the parent, "temp") to the subfolder(s) that your installer makes.  The permissions on the parent "temp" folder ARE intact?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks. I tried to explain it in a new edit.

Answer (score 1):

That Temp folder is about as close to a free-for-all as you're going to get on Windows. By default the "Users" group of the PC have *full control* of it, so you can't trust it to be in any expected state.

The only answer is to alter your installer to ensure it's applying the permissions it needs to the folders it's creating, instead of depending on (possibly missing/incorrect) inherited permissions.

Comment: Yes, that's what the developers did. But you pointed out the main problem `so you can't trust it to be in any expected state`. From my internet seraches I know that it can happen to any folder. So I (primary not a developer) look for the cause and a way to indentify such constellation. In this case it's only annoying. On other folders it can be a serious security leak.

Comment: Yes, the permissions can be removed from any folder, or set however the computer's owner feels like setting them.  You can't trust an OS that isn't yours, and you can't trust it will be setup the way you expect it to be. If you want to figure out specifically _why_ folders you use/have access to lose these permissions, it'll take file auditing as CharlesH suggested in his comment.